# Time series: What is my natural time period?

Tags: time-series, modeling, frequency

We are modeling univariate ts with R. Sampled daily since 1-1-2013 at five observations per week.

We are unclear about how to decide 'natural time period'. Until now we just assumed 260 weekdays in a year (frequency = 260). We understand that our data is too short to allow discovery of yearly seasonals, and hence that is not in scope, we just look for non-seasonal model.

So is it nonsense to specify frequency 260? Maybe we should select Week as natural time period and set frequency 5?

How should we decide this, and how does it impact the modeling process?

Comment: If you have evenly spaced data points (which you do, if we ignore weekends), it's best to use that time period. So, yes, in your case, a day would be the correct time period. You might be confusing Fourier analysis with natural time period?

Comment: Is *natural time period* something required by a specific R function? If yes, you should ask for an explanation of this parameter and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @barrycarter Thx for comments. Function ts() requires you specify the frequency. Mr Hyndmann spoke somewhere about 'If one week is your natural time period then you should specify frequency 7'. We look for more guidance on impact of this parameter in analysis. And yes, we are confusing a lot of things :) Trying time series modeling without solid results so far.

Comment: @barrycarter So you are proposing to set frequency 1 then? Or do I misunderstand.